# Ajax return 0 in plugin - ajax only used in wp-admin

Tags: plugins, ajax, wp-admin

i use ajax a lot and have no problams with it. This time i am trying to use ajax inside wp-admin and only their aka this is not a "nopriv" issuse.

This is being used inside a plugin i am writing.

**For some reason i am getting a 0 returned.**
Since the js file is enqueue'd inside that php file it cant be a matter
of file wasnt found. i guess i am missing something as to how ajax should be
written when using it inside wp-admin ?

**Here is the JS file:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('#sgxcsParentTax').change(function() {

        var selected    =   $(this).val()

        $.post(ajax_object.ajaxurl, {
            action: 'action_sgxtax_chainedselect',
            selected: selected
        }, function(data) {
            var $response       = $(data);
            var cats            = $response.filter('#cats').html();

            // HANDLE SUCCESS >>
            if(cats) {
                $(this).append(cats);
            }

        });

    });

});
```

**Here is the PHP file:**

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-sgxtax-chainedselect', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'/ajax-taxonomy_chained_selector.js', array('jquery'), 1.0 );
wp_localize_script( 'ajax-sgxtax-chainedselect', 'ajax_object', array('ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )) );


// GRAB SUB CATEGORIES
add_action('wp_ajax_action_sgxtax_chainedselect', 'ajax_sgxtax_chainedselect');
function ajax_sgxtax_chainedselect() {


    echo 'I AM WORKING!'; 

    die();
}
```

Can anyone spot the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i went ahead and changed all my code according to several examples i found across the web.

p.s 
i came to the conclusion my code is ok but isnt suitable for the accepted structered that needs to be used for ajax inside wp-admin.

In any case...
Here is a version that works. in the hope this might helps someone

**The JS**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('#sgxcsParentTax').change(function() {

        var selected    =   $(this).val();

        data = {
            action: 'sgxcs_get_childcats',
            selected: selected
        }

        $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
            var $response       = $(response);
            var childcats       = $response.filter('#childcats').html();

            // HANDLE SUCCESS >>
            if(childcats) {
                $('#sgxcsChildTax').html(childcats);
            }           
        });

    });

});
```

**The Php...**

```
function get_childcats_ajax(){

    echo 'I AM WORKING! (finally)'; 

    die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_sgxcs_get_childcats', 'get_childcats_ajax');
```